# Modify $_schema variable of a model for validation

Tags: php, cakephp

My current model has an attribute 'param' which stores details like email, phone, website in serialized manner. Now I wish to apply validation to those details and display corresponding error messages to view.
To accomplish this, i want to modify my current $_schema variable of model and apply validations as if those were model attributes. Now I wish to know how to modify this variable. I tried to use constructor but in constructor, the variable $_schema shows an error that it empty. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I don't full understand your question, can you provide some examples? Anyway, did you take a look at [custom validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods)?

Comment: You can even assign validation for fields that do not have any schema. But if you really want to also add schema definitions, see: https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Model/ContactForm.php#L12

Comment: @mark that was exactly what I wanted to do. I modifying schema variable would overwrite my existing schema derived from database.